# WPF global open/close dialog event?

Tags: wpf, events, dialog, event-handling

In my WPF application I would like to subscribe to some event/callbeck/whatever that tells me whenever a dialog window opens (and closes) in my application.

I found the window collection but this is a simple container and it doesn't seem to provide any means of subscription.

I also tried using event handlers but there seems not be an event that tells me what I need.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it without a base class is adding a handler to MainWindow deactivated

If a new window is opened, the main window will lose focus = your "new window event"

```
private readonly List<Window> openWindows = new List<Window>();

public void ApplicationMainWindow_Deactivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
    {
        if (!openWindows.Contains(window) && window != sender)
        {
            // Your window code here
            window.Closing += PopupWindow_Closing;
            openWindows.Add(window);
        }
    }
}

private void PopupWindow_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    var window = (Window)sender;
    window.Closing -= PopupWindow_Closing;
    openWindows.Remove(window);
}
```

Comment: Would this also get triggered if the user clicked to another running application?

Answer (score 1):

Without creating a Base class for all your windows where you can hook into the opened event (or manually adding the opened event to each window), I'm not sure how you'd be able to know when new windows were create.

There may be a more elegant way, but you could poll the `Application.Current.Windows` to see if any new windows were created while keeping track of the one's you've found.

Here is a crude example that will demonstrate how to use a `DispatchTimer` to poll for new windows, keep track of found windows and hook into the closed event.

**Code Behind**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private DispatcherTimer Timer { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Window> Windows { get; private set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // add current Window so we don't add a hook into it
        Windows = new ObservableCollection<Window> { this };

        Timer = new DispatcherTimer( DispatcherPriority.Background );
        Timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds( 500 );
        Timer.Tick += ( _, __ ) => FindNewWindows();
        Timer.Start();

        this.WindowListBox.ItemsSource = Windows;
        this.WindowListBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Title";
    }

    private void FindNewWindows()
    {
        foreach( Window window in Application.Current.Windows )
        {
            if( !Windows.Contains( window ) )
            {
                window.Closed += OnWatchedWindowClosed;
                // inserting at 0 so you can see it in the ListBox
                Windows.Insert( 0, window );
                Feedback.Text = string.Format( "New Window Found: {0}\r\n{1}",
                                                window.Title, Feedback.Text );
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnWatchedWindowClosed( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        var window = (Window)sender;
        Windows.Remove( window );
        Feedback.Text = string.Format( "Window Closed: {0}\r\n{1}",
                                        window.Title, Feedback.Text );
    }

    private void CreateWindowButtonClick( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
    {
        string title = string.Format( "New Window {0}", DateTime.Now );
        var win = new Window
                    {
                            Title = title,
                            Width = 250,
                            Height = 250,
                            Content = title,
                    };

        win.Show();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox Name="WindowListBox"
                Width="251"
                Height="130"
                Margin="12,12,0,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBox Name="Feedback"
                Width="479"
                Height="134"
                Margin="12,148,0,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
    <Button Name="CreateWindowButton"
            Width="222"
            Height="130"
            Margin="269,12,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Click="CreateWindowButtonClick"
            Content="Create New Window"
            FontSize="20" />
</Grid>
```

Click away and create as many new windows as you want; then close them. You'll see the feedback as it happens. Granted, there will be a 500ms delay whenever a new window is created since the `DispatchTimer`'s interval is set at 500ms.

Answer (score 1):

You could register a class handler in App.cs as demonstrated here

https://gist.github.com/mwisnicki/3104963

```
    ...
    EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(UIElement), FrameworkElement.LoadedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnLoaded), true);
    EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(UIElement), FrameworkElement.UnloadedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnUnloaded), true);
    ...        

    private static void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is Window)
            Console.WriteLine("Loaded Window: {0}", sender);
    }

    private static void OnUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is Window)
            Console.WriteLine("Unloaded Window: {0}", sender);
    }
```

The link above seems to register an empty handler on instances to make things work properly.

Comment: I think this is the "cleanest" of the solutions shown for this question. I'm not sure if Loaded / Opened and Unloaded / Closed are semantically equivalent exactly, but they seem close enough. This is the approach I am using, anway.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of any global open/close event.

It should somehow be possible to do, but that provides that you have control over all windows opening and closing. Like if you build a "base window" (which naturally inherit "Window") that all your dialogs windows inherit from.

Then you clould have a static event on the "base window" which you fire from the base window's opening and closing/closed (or unloaded) events, sending "this" as "sender".
You can attafh to that static event in your App.xaml.cs class.

It's a hack, but it's possible.

Comment: I am afraid thats not a solution for me. There is code I can not change so I can not use a common base for each dialog.

Comment: May I ask, only by my own curiosity, what you need this for?

Comment: Automated GUI based software testing. Of course I want to have control over dialogs too.

Comment: Ah.  Then you should check out the new stuff about unit testing in Visual Studio 2012. Stuff like that may be supported natively :-)